# In meteor, using iron:router how to redirect user to page 404 if the path is not defined?

Tags: meteor

I use Meteor 1.0 and iron:router. I currently redirect users with the following 2 routes definitions:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('home_page');
});

Router.route('/about', function () {
  this.render('about');
});
```

How can I define a route for undefined routes (error 404) ?  For instance, if a user go to the url "/blablabla", I want him to be redirected to /404 which would refer to a template.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I used to have a catch-all route defined (`"/*"`) but that stopped working with my update to Meteor 1.0, so went looking for a better way and I noticed that you can configure a `notFoundTemplate`. That seems to do the trick for me. It use the `layoutTemplate` as the base and just fills in the `yield` with the `notFoundTemplate` which is exactly what I wanted.

```
Router.configure({layoutTemplate: 'layout', notFoundTemplate: '404'});
```

Comment: `notFoundTemplate` has been there since March, if not earlier.

Comment: @DanDascalescu, thanks for that back story. With a rapidly changing platform and blog posts lasting forever, it's sometimes hard to keep up with the history. I only started using Meteor 6-8 weeks ago and I've gone through two updates. My catch-all route stopped working only when I updated to 1.0 so that's when I found notFoundTemplate. Do you know if the plugin that you mentioned is even necessary any more? Is it possible that dataNotFound is more for server-side data-oriented routes but notFoundTemplate is more for situations like what JLavoie and I were trying to do?

Comment: @Larry, your best bet is to [file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues). The folks there are super responsive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `dataNotFound` iron-router plugin that deals with undefined routes:

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#plugins

Comment: I added the following code and nothing happens:    Router.plugin('dataNotFound', {notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'});

Comment: I tried the same thing myself and got the same lack of results, but then I switched to just specifying a `notFoundTemplate` in the Router.configure (see my answer) and that worked. I'm guessing that the plugin was sucked into the base iron:router and is now configured with Router.configure, but that's just a guess.

Comment: In discovermeteor, at the end of chapter 5 'routing', it is suggested to add `Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound', _{only: 'yourTemplate'}_);` after the routes. Translations are free but not the original version so i cant give a link